# Critical NSSstring Problem in Facebook friend Recovery(IPhone Development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

My Question is regarding special Character in NSString.

Actual name:-  Yusuf Doğan

Retrieve name=  Yusuf Do\u011fan

My Actual fb friend name is  Yusuf Doğan  (Check Special "g with ~ cap").

I take it as NSdata and then converter it in to nsstring.

NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

But the nsstring shows it as

"Yusuf Do\u011fan"

Similar cause with the following.

Ricsi Zoványi   as       Ricsi Zov\u00e1nyi

Pero Perić      as       Pero Peri\u0107

Any Solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
        NSString *source = [NSString stringWithString:_username];
        [_username release];
        NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:source];
        [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
        while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
            NSString *chunk;

            // Scan up to the Unicode marker
            [scanner scanUpToString:@"\\u" intoString:&chunk];
            // Append the chunk read
            [result appendString:chunk];

            // Skip the Unicode marker
            if ([scanner scanString:@"\\u" intoString:nil]) {

                // Read the Unicode value (assume they are hexa and four)
                unsigned int value;
                NSRange range = NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 4);
                NSString *code = [source substringWithRange:range];
                [[NSScanner scannerWithString:code] scanHexInt:&value];
                unichar c = (unichar) value;

                // Append the character
                [result appendFormat:@"%C", c];

                // Move the scanner past the Unicode value
                [scanner scanString:code intoString:nil];
            }
        }
        _username = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",result] retain];
        [result release];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "NSUTF8StringEncoding" use "NSUTF16StringEncoding". I think this may solve your issue.